# Will android update Name and Icon of the app automatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android application in Market Place. And, when I download it say it will be displayed with Name  "XYZ" and with Image1 as an Icon.

Now when I update the app and in the code if I set the New Name and New image as an Icon: 
Now I download the app from Market place and install in the same device where my old app is there.

So will it update the Name and Icon of the existing app automatically? If not what measures we need to take so that Name and Image of already exisitng app are updated and the total app is not re-installed.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know, until now all updates are going to "re-install" the app somehow. so you upload your new apk to the developer console (with increades version number) and the market will provide the "update" to all users.

now, the update is simply to re-install your app as it is not possible for Google to tell, what part of your codes has changed...

so, the name of the app and the icon will change, but your app is also going to be re-installed (please correct me, if I'm wrong...)

Answer (score 0):

When you update information like name and app icon, it could take a day before you can see any update on the Play Store. But on your device, if you have your app icon on your home screen, just remove it and replace it by the one in the apps list